# C# label text not change in method

Tags: c#, label

I am new in the middle of the c#.

I have a problem, I want to change the text of a textboxbut I do not happen I have to look on the forum but nothing helped me. Your help will be welcome.

create textbox:

```
        TextBox _DysplayRulsR = new TextBox();

        _DysplayRulsR.Text = "Hello message";
        _DysplayRulsR.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        _DysplayRulsR.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        _DysplayRulsR.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        _DysplayRulsR.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        _DysplayRulsR.IsReadOnly = true;
        _DysplayRulsR.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        _DysplayRulsR.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        _DysplayRulsR.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);
        _DysplayRulsR.Width = 900;
        _DysplayRulsR.Height = 300;
        _DysplayRulsR.FontSize = 30;
        _DysplayRulsR.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        _ContentGrid.Children.Add(_DysplayRulsR);
```

_ContentGrid = Grid

method change textbox text:

```
     public static void UpdateRules(string status)
    {
        _DysplayRulsR.Text = "done";
    }
```

The label is displayed well the method and well used but the text of the textbox_DysplayRuls does not want to change.

Sorry for my approximate English I'm really not strong for translation.

Comment: it should be `_TextRules.Text = "done";`

Comment: Your TextBox doesn't belong to a container.

Comment: @larsTech 

If of course I do not put all the code so that it is clearer,             _ContentGrid.Children.Remove(_DysplayRuls);

Comment: What kind of control is ContentGrid?  Why are you trying to put a label in it?  Why are you removing it?  What's _TextRules?  In your attempt to simplify your post, you have left many open questions.

Comment: The cleanest way to do this is to Bind the text to a property making sure the binding  mode is TwoWay. Then update the property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an issue with naming conventions.  This may seem like a nit, but in this case it is a clue to the overall problem.

This line:

```
TextBox _DysplayRulsR = new TextBox();
```

...smells bad.  If a variable name begins with an underscore, it should be a member variable.  Some devs think the underscore is unnecessary, but that is a different point; if you're going to use them at all, they should not be used for local variables.

This leads me to believe that this line:

```
public static void UpdateRules(string status)
{
    _DysplayRulsR.Text = "done";
}
```

...is actually referencing a different textbox with a name of `_DysplayRulsR` but at member, not local, scope.

So you have two options:

Change this

```
TextBox _DysplayRulsR = new TextBox();
```

to this:

```
_DysplayRulsR = new TextBox();
```

OR

Add this to your first block of code:

```
_DysplayRulsR.Name = "_DysplayRulsR";
```

And change this:

```
public static void UpdateRules(string status)
{
    _DysplayRulsR.Text = "done";
}
```

to this:

```
public static void UpdateRules(string status)
{
    _ContentGrid.Children.FindControl("_DysplayRulsR").Text = "done";
}
```

Comment: A big thank you for your help, a silly mistake. But these are some of the mistakes that are made. Good day to you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `Text` property of your TextBox .

Example:

```
public static void UpdateRules(string status)
{
    _TextRules.Text = "done";
}
```

However you did show `_DysplayRuls` as the name of your TextBox in your above initialization code.  Make sure you replace `_TextRules` in my example with whatever TextBox you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a new value to the Text property of your _DysplayRuls TextBox instance.

```
public static void UpdateRules(string status)
{
    _DysplayRuls.Text = "done";
}
```